# Query/Replace element in DataFrame with element directly beneath it

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I need to query and replace 0.00s with a value directly below it **if certain conditions are met**. I have looked for documentation on such a behavior but have been unable to find an efficient Pythonic solution.

The logic is as follows:

**IF [Symbol] = 'VIX' AND [QuoteDateTime] CONTAINS '09:31:00' AND [Close]  = '0.00'**

**THEN** I would like to replace the [Close] value with the [Close] value right below it.

```
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
|    | Symbol |    QuoteDateTime    |  Close  |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
|  0 | VIX    | 2019-04-11 09:31:00 |    0.00 |
|  1 | VIX    | 2019-04-11 09:32:00 |   14.24 |
|  2 | VIX    | 2019-04-11 09:33:00 |   14.40 |
|  3 | SPX    | 2019-04-11 09:31:00 | 2911.09 |
|  4 | SPX    | 2019-04-11 09:32:00 | 2911.55 |
|  5 | SPX    | 2019-04-11 09:33:00 | 2915.22 |
|  6 | VIX    | 2019-04-12 09:31:00 |    0.00 |
|  7 | VIX    | 2019-04-12 09:32:00 |   15.64 |
|  8 | VIX    | 2019-04-12 09:33:00 |   15.80 |
|  9 | SPX    | 2019-04-12 09:31:00 | 2901.09 |
| 10 | SPX    | 2019-04-12 09:32:00 | 2901.55 |
| 11 | SPX    | 2019-04-12 09:33:00 | 2905.22 |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
```

**Expected output** would be that Index 0 [Close] is 14.24 and Index 6 [Close] is 15.64. Everything else remains the same.

```
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
|    | Symbol |    QuoteDateTime    |  Close  |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
|  0 | VIX    | 2019-04-11 09:31:00 |   14.24 |
|  1 | VIX    | 2019-04-11 09:32:00 |   14.24 |
|  2 | VIX    | 2019-04-11 09:33:00 |   14.40 |
|  3 | SPX    | 2019-04-11 09:31:00 | 2911.09 |
|  4 | SPX    | 2019-04-11 09:32:00 | 2911.55 |
|  5 | SPX    | 2019-04-11 09:33:00 | 2915.22 |
|  6 | VIX    | 2019-04-12 09:31:00 |   15.64 |
|  7 | VIX    | 2019-04-12 09:32:00 |   15.64 |
|  8 | VIX    | 2019-04-12 09:33:00 |   15.80 |
|  9 | SPX    | 2019-04-12 09:31:00 | 2901.09 |
| 10 | SPX    | 2019-04-12 09:32:00 | 2901.55 |
| 11 | SPX    | 2019-04-12 09:33:00 | 2905.22 |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create boolean mask by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==`, [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for strings from `datetimes` and set new values by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
#convert to datetimes if necessary
df['QuoteDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['QuoteDateTime'])

mask = (df['Symbol'].eq('VIX') & 
        df['QuoteDateTime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').eq('09:31:00') &
        df['Close'].eq(0))

df['Close'] = df['Close'].mask(mask, df['Close'].shift(-1))
#alternative1
#df.loc[mask, 'Close'] = df['Close'].shift(-1)
#alternative2
#df['Close'] = np.where(mask, df['Close'].shift(-1), df['Close'])
print (df)

   Symbol       QuoteDateTime    Close
0     VIX 2019-04-11 09:31:00    14.24
1     VIX 2019-04-11 09:32:00    14.24
2     VIX 2019-04-11 09:33:00    14.40
3     SPX 2019-04-11 09:31:00  2911.09
4     SPX 2019-04-11 09:32:00  2911.55
5     SPX 2019-04-11 09:33:00  2915.22
6     VIX 2019-04-12 09:31:00    15.64
7     VIX 2019-04-12 09:32:00    15.64
8     VIX 2019-04-12 09:33:00    15.80
9     SPX 2019-04-12 09:31:00  2901.09
10    SPX 2019-04-12 09:32:00  2901.55
11    SPX 2019-04-12 09:33:00  2905.22
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert, but you could try using the index:

First get the index with this *short* line:

`idx = df.index[(df['Symbol'] == 'VIX') & (df['QuoteDateTime'].str.contains("09:31:00")) & (df['Close'] == '0.0')]`

Then use the index to set the values to the values in the rows below:

`df.loc[idx, 'Close'] = df.loc[idx+1, 'Close'].values`

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I will use your method as a backup. It worked after a slight modification - `idx = df.index[(df['Symbol'].eq('VIX')) & (df['QuoteDateTime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').eq('09:31:00')) & (df['Close'].eq(0))]` I like the logic here.

Comment: Of course! ... and yeah `.eq()` was nicer than `==`.